# modals inside a php code

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server

i have a table in PHP with id name and 3 buttons
(1st show details / 2 to edit / 3 to delete) to display a table in my database
and what i want to do is when a customer press on of them a to pop up a modal
how can i do such thing?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Jobs";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($connection,$sql);
$counter=1;
while($row4=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
 {
  echo"<tr >";
  echo"<td class='text-center'>".$counter."</td>";
  echo"<td class='text-center'>".$row4[0]."</td>";
  echo"<td class='text-center'>".$row4[1]."</td>";
  echo"<td class='text-center'> 
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>show</button>
   <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>edit</button>
   <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>delete</button>
   </td>";
   echo"</tr>";
   $counter++;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You'd need to either include javascript on the page that listens to click events to reveal or create a modal to present and then load the data to show, or you could make the table rows link to another page where you can render your modal HTML. Modal dialogs are more of a client side JS thing than a server side PHP thing.

Comment: and how can i link the table rows with another page.? with ahref? or with if(isset($_POST['button1']))

Comment: You can use an anchor tag as a wrapper for the table row content and use `href` to point to another PHP file if you want to display a modal using two different pages. I'd use javascript to show the modal on the same page though personally.

Comment: thank you for your help i will try it to see if something happens...i am not too familiar with java script to be honest that's the problem